# clang++ not seeing definition that g++ sees

Tags: c++, c++11, ubuntu

On updating ubuntu from 15.04 to 15.10, I see changes in how clang resolves references to some libraries.  (I think this is not an ubuntu question but rather a clang question and that I've missed some subtlety on how clang has recently changed.)

Here's a tiny test example designed only to tickle the phenomenon:

```
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << argc << " - " << argv[0] << std::endl;
    Json::Reader reader;
    Json::Value root;
    reader.parse("", root, false);
    std::cout << reader.getFormattedErrorMessages() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile like this

```
clang++ -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -o json_test json_test.cc -ljsoncpp

/tmp/json_test-680d3a.o: In function `main':
/tmp/json_test.cc:10: undefined reference to `Json::Reader::getFormattedErrorMessages() const'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And yet the definition appears to be present:

```
jeff@birdsong:src $ objdump -TC /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so | grep getFormatted
000000000000e190 g    DF .text  00000000000004d2  Base        Json::OurReader::getFormattedErrorMessages[abi:cxx11]() const
000000000000dc70 g    DF .text  00000000000004d2  Base        Json::Reader::getFormattedErrorMessages[abi:cxx11]() const
jeff@birdsong:src $
```

The abi:cxx11 suggests I might at least try this

```
clang++ -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -o json_test json_test.cc -ljsoncpp
```

but same error.  On the other hand, this works fine:

g++ -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -o json_test json_test.cc -ljsoncpp

Fwiw, here's version info:

```
jeff@birdsong:tmp $ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

jeff@birdsong:tmp $ clang++ --version
Ubuntu clang version 3.6.2-1 (tags/RELEASE_362/final) (based on LLVM 3.6.2)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
jeff@birdsong:tmp $
```

Comment: Gcc-5 got into some painful ABI change that clang couldn't immediately follow.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Aha.  Is there a work-around aside from hand-compiling quite a lot of librarires?

Comment: In the clang 3.6 readme, I see "transition to gcc 5" at 1:3.6.2-1).

Comment: I've filed this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libjsoncpp/+bug/1510042

Comment: Sorry for the silly question; I always specify my libraries before the input files, have you tried `clang++ -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14  -ljsoncpp -o json_test json_test.cc` ?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn No difference